# Can I put html code as an onChain NFT?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft, chaindata, code

Can I put html code as an on-chain NFT?
I don't want the NFT to be an image, I would like it to hold html code.
e.g the NFT will be Hello world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an attribute in the metadata and attach the html code to that. If you don't want to add any image to the NFT, leave the `image` field empty.

But obviously that code snippet will be visible if your dApp is reading that attribute property holding the html code.

Comment: So in that case, will opensea and other marketplaces display it if I place it in the "animation_url" prop?

Comment: `animation_url` is for multimedia. You can HTML page links to it. It has been mentioned by opensea(https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards)
You can push your html file to ipfs and add that ipfs path to the `animation_url`